# PHP cURL SSL Connect Error

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have tried to display content of SSL webpage using file_get_contents() function.

```
$url = base64_decode("aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGVudGtvdHRhLmNvbQ==");
echo file_get_contents($url);

$header = array("Connection: Keep-Alive", "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3600);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

But it throws me a warning says,

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in
```

Then I tried to get using cURL library. But it also gives me an error no 35 which is SSL Connect Error.

I have searched on cURL site and it says error while connecting webpage.

> CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR (35)
>
> A problem occurred somewhere in the SSL/TLS handshake. You really want the error buffer and read the message there as it pinpoints the problem slightly more. Could be certificates (file formats, paths, permissions), passwords, and others.

could you please anyone help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### TLDR:

I fixed up your code. Here is a working example:

```
$url = base64_decode("aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGVudGtvdHRhLmNvbQ==");

$header = array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

### A Longer Explanation

After base64 decoding `$url` is equal to `https://www.tentkotta.com` which (when requested with the code in your question) returns an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error:

```
https://www.tentkotta.com
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Sat, 04 Jun 2016 02:15:19 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.21
Set-Cookie: kohanasession=jfl6dh4k386htjpgmh99ns54t1; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: kohanasession=jfl6dh4k386htjpgmh99ns54t1; path=/
Set-Cookie: kohanasession_data=c2Vzc2lvbl9pZHxzOjI2OiJqZmw2ZGg0azM4Nmh0anBnbWg5OW5zNTR0MSI7dG90YWxfaGl0c3xpOjE7X2tmX2ZsYXNoX3xhOjA6e311c2VyX2FnZW50fHM6MDoiIjtpcF9hZGRyZXNzfHM6MTI6Ijk5LjE1MC4yNDUuNCI7bGFzdF9hY3Rpdml0eXxpOjE0NjUwMDY1MTk7TEFTVF9BQ1RJVklUWXxpOjE0NjUwMDY1MTk7Q2l0eUlEfHM6MjoiMTMiOw%3D%3D; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Length: 828
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.tentkotta.com/themes/pink/css/style.css" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.tentkotta.com/themes/pink/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<div class="container_outer" >
<div class="container_inner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content_fourty_four_page">
            <div class="error_inner_page">
            <div class="error_left_im">
                    <img src="https://www.tentkotta.com/themes/pink/images/404_error_img.png"  alt="404 error" />
            </div>
            <div class="error_right_cont">
            <img src="https://www.tentkotta.com/themes/pink/images/error_right_im.png"  alt="404 error" />
            <p>The page you’re looking for cannot be found.</p>
            <a href="javascript:history.back();" title="Back">Back</a>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

To stop causing errors on the server side, you need to change this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

`CURLOPT_HEADER` is for response headers. `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is for request headers. See the [`curl_setopt` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for details.

Also, remove this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 3);
```

SSLv3 has likely been disabled on your target URL due to the [POODLE vulnerability](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html). Just let cURL and the host negotiate the best protocol instead of specifying it yourself.

Additionally, the following lines are not necessary since https://www.tentkotta.com does appear to have a valid SSL Certificate:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

Also, if you want the `$result` variable to contain the response body of the HTTP request, you should add this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Beyond that many of your other settings such as `"Connection: Keep-Alive"`, `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE` aren't helping in this example and can safely be removed.

Comment: thank you for your time. Site is completely working on web browser. I would like to display the contents. I'm not owner of the site. I cannot modify it from server. How could I be able to display in result?

Comment: I included a working example at the top of my answer. Please try it.

Comment: it gave me same error "cURL error (35): SSL connect error" on my localhost MAMP

Comment: `cURL error (35): SSL connect error` is caused by this line: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 3);`. If you're getting that error, you must not be running my example code which doesn't include that line.

Comment: I'm running your example. I just copy and paste it and checked.

Comment: yes it does working on command line. but not on MAMP server. even in my webserver

Comment: It must be that either you haven't deployed it, you're hitting a different host than you think you're hitting, the response is cached, you're not testing in the environment you think you're testing in, something. But the example code works as you have demonstrated to yourself by running it on the command line. Now you just have to figure out what code you're *really* running when you're doing your browser testing.

Comment: I have used Mac's default php in command line. but after I check that with MAMP's php in command line it gave me same error.

Comment: I'm not a MAMP user so I can't say with certainty why you're experiencing that. I still have a strong suspicion that your MAMP php is not running the file you think it's running. Try introducing a syntax error into the file and run it with MAMP. What should happen is that the file won't even compile. If instead of that you still see `cURL error (35): SSL connect error`, then you know for sure there is some other file that MAMP is running instead of the one you think it's running.

Comment: I have already tried that and it is running the correct file. it does showing the other error

Comment: Try upgrading MAMP and its cURL and OpenSSL dependencies. If you're getting `cURL error (35): SSL connect error` with cURL defaults, you may have some old libs. As you can see, even the built-in OSX php can run the example code without error.